# Recurring action when a user leaves a place

Tags: gwt, gwt-activities

I want to schedule a recurring action in my Activity (I am using Activities and Places design pattern). When my user leaves a place associated with this activity, how quickly can I expect this action to stop? Will the inclusion of the recurring action somehow affect the way an Activity is disposed of?

I don't need an immediate guarantee. If an activity is disposed of normally, it's acceptable in my use case.

Comment: How do you _schedule a recurring action_?

Comment: Scheduler with scheduleFixedDelay()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is your responsibility to cancel anything that you started in your activity, if you need/want so.

With a `Scheduler.RepeatingCommand`, you'd have to keep the command around and, in the activity's `onStop`, set a flag on it so that the next time it's run it exits early and returns `false`.